# How to correct figure placement?

Tags: floats

I've placed two figures in the same heading `Specification and Design` but when I compile the document in TexStudio, the second graphic `Proposed physio application prototype system architecture` is shown under a different heading `Results and Evaluation`

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

This is the section of document where I've placed the two figures:

```
\subsection{Specification and Design}
\label{sec:Specification and Design}


\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{ Proposed project time line.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{initial_timieline}
\end{figure}





The platform being used for the application was initially proposed to be a Windows Universal application.But the C sharp wrapper being used to interface with the Myo arm band relies heavily on platform invocations which the Windows Universal application platform doesn't support. Owing to this the platform chosen for development was windows presentation foundation.




\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{ Proposed physio application prototype system architecture, detailing flow of user input.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{gesture_arc}
\end{figure}




\subsection{Implementation}
\label{sec:Implementation}



\section{Results and Evaluation}
```

Output:

[image: figure incorrect output placement]

Comment: The figures are floating, which is a good thing. But you can do `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`.

Comment: `[h]` is more or less a request for the figure to go to the end of the document You would have had a warning that latex is changing it to `[ht]` but using `[htp]` is better. `[h]` means that the float is not allowed at top of page (no `t`) or on a page of floats (no `p`) so it doesn't give latex many options to place it anywhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added [htp] to the figure but that didn't change the placement. Is there an extra step I'm missing?

Comment: as shown in the answers to the linked question by default latex does not even try to keep floats in the same section,. section boundaries are not visible to the float mechanism at all unless the section forces a new page, as `\chapter` normally does. `placeins` package is probably what you should look for (but `[h]` is always an error in any case:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the `[h]` from the param, now it is `[tp]`. I also included this package as mentioned above `\usepackage{placeins}` yet the figure still outputs to the incorrect chapter. Any idea why?

Comment: @BrianJ Please compare with the above: `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` If you do not want the behaviour globally, you have to manually add `\FloatBarrier` *before* the next section.